# Java Stream - Convert List to Map using toMap

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to stream() and thinking of refactoring the following code with `stream()`.

```java
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Date birthDate;
}

public class Post {
    private String content;
    private User user;
}

// I have a list of Users
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

// Goal is to initialize a Map of users -> List<Post>
Map<User, List<Post>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (User user : users) {
    map.put(user, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

I tried the following but doesn't work out.

```java
Map<String, List<Post>> map = users.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(user, new ArrayList<>()));
```

Any suggestion on how to make it right?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're aware of `Collectors.toMap`, you must be aware of the functional interfaces it accepts, probably lambda expressions and other stuff. How can, do you think, `user` be converted to a string for the key; "list to list" for the value?

Comment: Note: you are using `Date`, which I assume is `java.util.Date`. Don't use it, it's obsolete. Instead, use classes from the `java.time` package. In your case, you may want to use `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, because you aren't using a lambda. You are just trying to pass the objects to the `toMap` method which doesn't work.

```
users.stream()
    // Function.identity/() is the same as writing u -> u.
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), u -> new ArrayList<>()));
```

Comment: Thanks very much!